# Stuck at login + nvidia* purged

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

This question is popular however I searched and couldn't find a solution that fits unless I missed it somewhere. Please do not downvote before reading.

I have nvidia-387 driver installed and my system was working. I wanted to install cuda so I went with nvidia-390. This led to the login loop problem which I did not try to solve with this solution.

So I moved back to the nvidia-387 but i was stuck at login. I tried `nomodeset` and `nouveau.modeset=0` but none worked on the latest kernel I was using. `nouveau.modeset=0` did work on the 2nd kernel. So I went on and purged nvidia*. Now I am faced with the same problem on both kernels.

I am left with one kernel with which I can normally login.

How can I fix the other kernel(s) preferably without messing with the working one so I could get back to installing cuda?

System:

- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04
- Dell XPS 15 9560 with
- NVIDIA GTX 1050

**Additional info**

On the working kernel, running `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` I get:

```
nvidia-384
nvidia-387
nvidia-390
```

[image]

`apt-cache policy nvidia-\*` (also on working kernel; external monitor not working) output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VsQPVCZfK4/

**Update 1**

**Kernels listed in grub menu**

- **4.14.0-38**: the one I was using with nvidia-387 but couldn't turn on GPU from `nvidia-seettings`. It suffered from this problem. I also installed bumblebee and switched to `nvidia-390` before rebooting the system and ending up with the the black screen following the startup splash screen (even with `nomodeset`)
- **4.13.0-37**
- **4.3.0-119**: I was able to login to this yesterday but not after I tried `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (how silly of me; I expected to be asked for a confirmation before installation) which also installed `nvidia-390` and can no longer login.

Now I can no longer login to any of the above listed kernels. My system is encrypted. If there's a way to fix the above issue (maybe install the latest upstream kernel?) that would be great. If not how can I reinstall the system while preserving or backing up my home directory?

**Update 2**

I manged to get back in using the first kernel. To do this I used `root` in recovery mode to move `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` to `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf.bk`

The system is using `nvidia-390` however the `nvidia-settings` don't show a GPU option.

Comment: Does CUDA not work with the 387 driver series for some reason? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy nvidia-\*`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Updated. I did not say that. I though it would be good to use the latest version. Apparently, it wasn't.

Comment: You don't actually list the kernel versions that don't work and the one that does work. I think there were problems with nVidia supporting Meltdown and Spectre changes made for newest kernels which other people might spot if the relevant version numbers are in your question. Also you don't mention your nVidia model number and there may be problems with specific models others might spot.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I updated my question with the asked details.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up grabbing the latest version of Ubuntu Gnome and reinstalling (preserving the encrypted /home).

`Additional Drivers` showed me only one nvidia driver this time: `nvidia (proprietary, tested)` which I used. As far as I can see the GPU seems to be working as the NVIDIA settings shows more options I didn't have before and the Performance mode is now selected. I added screenshots below.

I tested switching between Performance and Power Saving modes and it works however I need to reboot the system counter to logging out and back in as the NVIDIA settings says.

Also, battery life is down drastically from 5-6 hours on Power Saving mode to 2.5 hours on Performance mode. This is expected.

[image]
[image]